# Is there a GUI front end for Nix package manager?

Tags: package-management

I've heard about [Nix package manager](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_package_manager) and how powerful it is, so I installed in my Ubuntu.

I was wondering if there is GUI front end for it (Like `pacman` simple GUI in Manjaro Linux) or It just runs using command line?

Comment: see here https://launchpad.net/~tomasz-kontusz/+archive/ubuntu/nix-daily

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

There is no GUI.
For a nicer CLI wrapper, you can use nox.

BTW the link from Dumindu Mahawela's comment is dead now - I didn't have time to work on that repository, and there are already dev packages for Nix available from Hydra.

Answer (score 1):

By now there is a UI at https://github.com/matejc/nixui. An accompanying blog post can be found at https://blog.matejc.com/blogs/myblog/nixs-very-own-graphical-ui.